# Unable to find the correct number for Project Euler 23

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to find the the problem for over 2 hours, the correct answer is 4179871 but I have only been getting 4177763,

> A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors
>   is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper
>   divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28
>   is a perfect number.
>
> A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is
>   less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.
>
> As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the
>   smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers
>   is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers
>   greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.
>   However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis
>   even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be
>   expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.
>
> Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as
>   the sum of two abundant numbers.

```
def factors(num) # function that returns array of factors
  factorsNums = []
  for i in 1..Math.sqrt(num).ceil
    if num % i == 0
      factorsNums.push(i) if i != num
      factorsNums.push(num / i) if ((num / i) < num) && ((factorsNums.include? (num / i)) == false)
    end
  end
  factorsNums
end
abundantNumbers = []

for i in 1..28123 #This loop will push into the array "abundantNumbers" each number from 1 to 28123 that is an abundant number (a number in which the sum of its divisors is bigger than the number itself)
  abundantNumbers.push(i) if factors(i).inject(0, :+) > i
end

abundantSums = []
#this 2 dimensional loop will find the every possible sum of 2 abundant numbers from which we got in the last for loop and push them into another array "abundantSums"
  for i in 0...abundantNumbers.length
    for j in i...abundantNumbers.length
      sum = abundantNumbers[i] + abundantNumbers[j]
      abundantSums.push(sum) if sum <= 28123
    end
  end


abundantSums = abundantSums.uniq.sort #remove duplicates and sort the array

notSums = []

for i in 1..28123 #find numbers which are not the sum of 2 abundant numbers and push them into the array "notSums"
  notSums.push(i) if (abundantSums.include? i) == false 
end
print notSums.inject(0, :+) #print out sum of array elements that are not sums of abundant numbers
```

Comment: @sawa, as I mentioned, I am expecting the program print 4179871, which is the correct answer, yet it is printing 4177763. I need need help To point out a logical error that I could not see that others might be able to see.

Comment: As @aimenalt or just add `uniq` (`factorsNums.uniq`) as returning value of `factors(num)`

Answer (score 2):

The issue was How the factors were handled, there were duplicates in the array containing factors and this is the fix:

```
def factors(num) # function that returns array of factors  
  factorsNums = []   
  for i in 1..Math.sqrt(num).ceil
    if num % i == 0
      factorsNums.push(i) if i != num && !factorsNums.include? i
      factorsNums.push(num / i) if ((num / i) < num) && ((factorsNums.include? (num / i)) == false)
    end   
  end   
  factorsNums 
end
```

Comment: If you cant' fix a problem in 2 hours, you probably can in 3 ;-) Well done!

Comment: `factors_original(6) # => [1, 2, 3, 3]` vs. `factors_fixed(6) # => [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @Stefan thanks mate! If you ever knew the frustration I felt, I was even testing out the function by itself with numbers that have repeated factors and it worked the way I thought it should but for a logical reason, some other other numbers with repeated factors, and sadly though I could've used a .uniq but I only looked up how to remove repeats in the middle of the program itself.

Comment: But that's why I never thought the issue came from the factors function. At least until I pasted someone's program for the same problem to solve and had them both output different data until I found what I needed.

Comment: Or an even better fix was to  just slap a .uniq after factorNums at the end and problem solved

Answer (score 1):

In constructing a method that returns an array of proper factors of a given positive interger, we can make use of the method [Prime::prime_division](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division), that determines the prime decomposition of every positive integer. For example,

```
require 'prime'

Prime.prime_division(180)
  #=> [[2, 2], [3, 2], [5, 1]]
```

This means that

```
180 = 2**2 * 3**2 * 5**1
```

Moreover, every factor of `180` equals

```
2**n2 * 3**n3 * 5**n5
```

where `0 << n2 << 2`, `0 << n3 << 2` and `0 <= n5 <= 1`. The *proper* factors are all factors other than `180`, which number

```
(2+1)*(2+1)*(1+1) - 1 #=> 17
```

We therefore can define the OP's method `factors` (which I've renamed `proper_factors`) as follows.

```
def proper_factors(n)
  first, *rest = Prime.prime_division(n).
                       map { |m,pow| (0..pow).map { |p| m**p } }
  first.product(*rest).
        map { |arr| arr.reduce(:*) } - [n]
end

proper_factors(180)
  #=> [1, 5, 3, 15, 9, 45, 2, 10, 6, 30, 18, 90, 4, 20, 12, 60, 36]
```

Next, create an array of abundant numbers between 12 and 28123.

```
max_val = 28123    
abundants = (12..max_val).select { |n| proper_factors(n).sum > n }
  #=> [12, 18, 20, 24, 30, 36, 40, 42, 48, 54, 56, 60, 66, 70, 72, 78, 80,
  #    ...
  #    12078, 12080, 12084, 12090, 12096, 12100, 12102, 12104, 12108, 12110,
  #    ...
  #    28086, 28092, 28098, 28100, 28104, 28110, 28112, 28116, 28120, 28122]
abundants.size
  #=> 6965
```

The sum of positive numbers that do not equal the sum of two abundant numbers equals the sum of numbers between 1 and 28123 (the sum of an arithmetic series) minus the sum of numbers between 1 and 28123 that equal the sum of two abundant numbers. Numbers that  equal the sum of two abundant numbers are easier to calculate than numbers that do not have that property, so we will calculate the desired sum as the difference between two sums.

The sum of numbers between 1 and 28123 equals

```
all_sum = 28123*(1+28123)/2
  #=> 395465626
```

We now calculate the sum of numbers between 1 and 28123 that equal the sum of two abundant numbers. To do that we merely accumulate (in an array) the sums of all pairs of abundant numbers that do not exceed `28123`. This will produce many duplicates, of course, so we must `uniq`ify the array before summing its values. (We could instead accumulate in a set.)

```
half_max = max_val/2
  #=> 14061
last_abundants_idx = abundants.size - 1
  #=> 6964

sum_nbrs_sum_two = abundants.each_with_index.with_object([]) do |(n,i),found|
  break found if n > half_max
  (i..last_abundants_idx).each do |j|
    m = n + abundants[j]
    break if m > max_val
    found << m
  end
end.uniq.sum
  #=> 391285755
```

Here the arrays `found` and `found.uniq` respectively contained `12148815` and  `26667` elements.<sup>1</sup>

The last step is the following.

```
all_sum - sum_nbrs_sum_two
  #=> 4179871
```

<sup>1 Notice that the third line contains the range `(i..last_abundants_idx)`, not  `(i+1..last_abundants_idx)`, to include the number `2*abundants[i]`. This is true for all `i`, but for most `i`, `2*abundants[i]` equals the sum of two different abundant numbers. In fact, if `i..` were changed to `i+1..` the sum (`391285755`) is only decreased by `64`.</sup>